# Pausing another song when starting another javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm trying to make it so that when you click on a separate element it pauses the current song playing from a different element. In addition I had previously made it so when you click on the same element after it started playing audio it would pause that audio, but when you click on a different element with the same function it breaks.

```
var paused = true;
var song;
var songPlaying;

function playSong(x) {
     song = x;

     if(songPlaying != song){
         document.getElementById(songPlaying).pause();
     }

     if(paused == true){
         document.getElementById(song).play();
         paused = false;
         songPlaying = song;
     } else {
         document.getElementById(song).pause();
         paused = true;
     }
 }
```

Is there anyway I can fix this? Will I have to make a different function for every song?

EDIT 1: Here the HTML my for the sections I'm using as well, each audio file has an ID that is called as a parameter in the function inside onclick

```
<div class="album">
    <img src="assets/BattalionsOfFear.png" onclick="playSong('bofSong')">
    <h1>Battalions of Fear</h1>
    <p>Released in 1988</p>
</div>

<div class="album">
    <img src="assets/FollowTheBlind.png" onclick="playSong('bfsSong')">
    <h1>Follow the Blind</h1>
    <p>Released in 1989</p>
</div>

<!--- Audio -->
<audio id="bofSong">
    <source src="assets/BattalionsOfFear.mp3">
</audio>

<audio id="bfsSong">
    <source src="assets/BanishFromSanctuary.mp3">
</audio>
```

EDIT 2:
In attempting Laif's solution 
I have tried adding the 'song' class to my HTML img elements and linked it to my audio element with the 'song1' class yet it still is not working. Am I doing the classes wrong or is it something with the way I have put them down?

```
<div class="album">
    <img src="assets/BattalionsOfFear.png" class="song song1">
    <h1>Battalions of Fear</h1>
    <p>Released in 1988</p>
</div>

<audio id="bofSong" class="song1">
    <source src="assets/BattalionsOfFear.mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each song should share the same class so that you can do something like this:

```
<html>
    <div class="song"></div>
    <div class="song"></div>
</html>
```

```
var songs = document.querySelectorAll(".song");

function playSong(e) {
  songs.forEach(el => {
    el.style.play();
  });
  e.currentTarget.pause();
};

songs.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", playSong);
});
```

Comment: The Audio element have the `paused` property. If it's false, it means the audio is playing. So I would extend this solution with a foreach to check all elements that is playing and then pause them.

Comment: Also, it is recommended to use "addEventListener" instead of "onclick".

Comment: With this solution how do I set unique songs for each element? Currently I have it so the audio has id that is used as a parameter for each elements onclick function in html.

Comment: @VictorGasior IDs must be unique, so they should already have unique identifiers if you are giving each audio an ID

Comment: @Laif Yes, but using this method how do I assign the IDs that I've made to be used for a certain element? For example, I want song A to play when image A is clicked and song B to play when image B is clicked. In my old method I used the ID as a function parameter inside the elements onclick="" to accomplish this, so how would I accomplish the same with this method?

Comment: @VictorGasior Elements can have multiple classes, so don’t use an ID, as a class that is shared only between the image and the actual audio so that they are tied together, so your class would be “song song1”

Comment: @Laif As detailed in my second edit after adding the classes in the fashion presented it still hasn't worked and do to my unfamiliarity with this method I don't know what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: @VictorGasior I've updated my code to work with my use case, you may need to adjust it slightly to work with your specific set up

Comment: @Laif I've tried using this solution and even slept on it, but every solution I try including changing the syntax, putting my javascript link at the bottom of the html doc, and using different class names have all not done anything. It always returns in the browser as, "Uncaught TypeError: el.style.play is not a function"

Comment: @VictorGasior Because it isn’t a function... I fired you wrote a function that would do that. Google how to pause and play with JavaScript and replace those.